# Making PHP cURL request on Windows yields "400 Bad Request" from proxy

Tags: php, windows, http, curl, proxy

Morning all

Basically, I am unable to make successful cURL requests to internal and external servers from my Windows 7 development PC because of an issue involving a proxy server.  I'm running cURL 7.21.2 thru PHP 5.3.6 on Apache 2.4.

Here's a most basic request that fails:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('http://www.google.com');

$log_file = fopen(sys_get_temp_dir() . 'curl.log', 'w');

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $log_file,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

@fclose($log_file);

print "<pre>{$response}";
```

The following (complete) response is received.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2012 17:12:58 GMT
Content-Length: 171
Content-Type: text/html
Server: IronPort httpd/1.1

Error response

Error code 400.

Message: Bad Request.

Reason: None.
```

The log file generated by cURL contains the following.

```
* About to connect() to proxy usushproxy01.unistudios.com port 7070 (#0)
*   Trying 216.178.96.20... * connected
* Connected to usushproxy01.unistudios.com (216.178.96.20) port 7070 (#0)
> GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Thu, 06 Sep 2012 17:12:58 GMT
< Content-Length: 171
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: IronPort httpd/1.1
< 
* Connection #0 to host usushproxy01.unistudios.com left intact
```

Explicitly stating the proxy and user credentials, as in the following, makes no difference: the response is always the same.

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init('http://www.google.com');

$log_file = fopen(sys_get_temp_dir() . 'curl.log', 'w');

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => $log_file,
    CURLOPT_PROXY => 'http://usushproxy01.unistudios.com:7070',
    CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD => '<username>:<password>',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

@fclose($log_file);

print "<pre>{$response}";
```

I was surprised to see an absolute URL in the request line ('GET ...'), but I think that's fine when dealing with proxy servers - according to the HTTP spec.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of options - including sending a user-agent, following this and that, etc, etc - having been through Stack Overflow questions, and other sites, but all requests end in the same response.

The same problem occurs if I run the script on the command line, so it can't be an Apache issue, right?

If I make a request using cURL from a *Linux* box on the same network, I don't experience a problem.

It's the "Bad Request" thing that's puzzling me: what on earth is wrong with my request?  Do you have any idea why I may be experiencing this problem?  A Windows thing?  A bug in the version of PHP/cURL I'm using?

Any help *very* gratefully received.  Many thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` ?

Comment: Thanks, @goldenparrot.  I did try that, but it didn't improve the situation.

Comment: You should add a UserAgent header. Might improve Googles perception.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking at an issue between cURL (different versions between Windows and Linux) and your IronPort version. In IronPort documentation:

> **Fixed: Web Proxy uses the Proxy-Connection header instead of the
>       Connection header, causing problems with some user agents**
>
> Previously, the Web Proxy used the Proxy-Connection header instead of the
>   Connection header when communicating with user agents with explicit
>   forward requests. Because of this, some user agents, such as Real
>   Player, did not work as expected. This no longer occurs. Now, the Web
>   Proxy replies to the client using the Connection header in addition to
>   the Proxy-Connection header. [Defect ID: 46515]

Try removing the `Proxy-Connection` (or add a `Connection`) header and see whether this solves the problem.

Also, you might want to compare the cURL logs between Windows and Linux hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the help, @lserni.  That sure was looking promising, but unfortunately it had no effect on my call.  I tried both combinations.  Thanks again, tho.